# Spring boot application not using the DB driver defined in application-test.properties

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc, spring-test

I decided I would like to add a h2 DB to my spring boot application for testing purposes. I added a new `application-test.properties` to my folder `test/resources` with all the necessary  configuration. The problem is that when I run the tests, I always get the connection to the mysql database.

I can see the `application-test.properties` is being used because the `loggin.level` changes from `DEBUG` to `ERROR` in my tests.

For my MySql DB I have a file which provides the datasource

#### Code

`application-test.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.h2.Driver

spring.h2.console.enabled=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.springframework.security=ERROR
```

`application.properties` file

```
mysql.database.host=localhost
mysql.database.port=3306
mysql.database.db=mydb
mysql.database.user=root
mysql.database.password=root
mysql.database.driver=mysql

logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

`datasource` class

```java
@Bean
open fun getDataSource(): DataSource? {
    val dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create()
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:$driver://$databaseHost:$databasePort/$databaseName")
    dataSourceBuilder.username(databaseUser)
    dataSourceBuilder.password(databasePassword)
    return dataSourceBuilder.build()
}
```

`test`

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class AdAccountControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Test
    fun `we should get unauthorized status when we dont provide credentials`() {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/ad-account"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk)
                .andDo(print())
    }


}
```

Comment: You should provide the error you are getting.

Comment: I am not getting an error, my DB is just always connecting to the MySql instead of the h2 when running the tests.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. This is not the problem though. Let me update my files.